# how do i place DIVS side by side on Dreamweaver design view

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

i have a rather annoying DIV problem, im working on dreamweaver CS5, and i have 2 DIVS inside of another container DIV. But they cant seem to stay next to each other on the design view of Dreamweaver, but when i preview them in a browser they are okay, they are only distorted in the design view, its kind of annoying working with them on top of each other.I have tried decreasing the size of the divs, but they just cant seem to stay side by side.! how do i solve this?

Comment: This does not have anything to do with php. Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

There is no substitute for a browser, or browsers as you need to test your site in all the latest browsers. I would switch off design view and have a browser open on the side or on your second monitor if you have one. You can setup scripts / browser add-ons that continuously refresh your browser so you can see your changes reflected.

Having said that, In Dreamweaver I suggest using live view instead of design view.

See that and other useful tips here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/10-useful-dreamweaver-tips-for-beginners/